# How to fix webpacker webpack-dev-server not recompiling on scss changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader, webpacker

I am using [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) for managing `javascript`, `scss` and `assets` in my rails project. I have used following command to run `webpack-dev-server`.

`bin/webpack-dev-server`

when ever I am changing `javascript` file content its recompiling and on page refresh getting updated content. But when I try the same with `scss` file changes its not updating.

Webpacker dev server is not re-compiling `scss` files on change.

Following is my `webpacker.yml` `dev_server` configuration:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  compile: false

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/
```

Following is the dependency

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jest": "^23.4.1",
    "jest-junit": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "1.16.4",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.10.0",
    "rails-erb-loader": "^5.5.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.2",
    "stylelint": "^9.2.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.5.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.0.0"
  }
```

#### Update: 1 ( `hmr: true` )

I tried to change the `dev_server` setting for `hmr: false` to `hmr: true` and at this time CSS files didn't even loaded. There was no request going in the network for fetching CSS files!!!

---

I expect on changing the `scss` file content `webpack-dev-server` will recompile automatically as it does for `js` file change, and when I refresh changes will be reflected in the page, without doing manual compilation.

Comment: Have you tried setting `hmr: true`?

Comment: @ErvalhouS `# Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true` I think this is for that, I will also try with `hmr: true`.

Comment: @ErvalhouS when I tried with `hmr: true` css files are not loading at all. But JSX file changes are reflecting properly.